# laravel elequent way to find single row from table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

hello I am new to laravel and maybe I am a bit confused between eloquent and query builder way for writing a query but anyway can you please tell me what could be the best eloquent way to retrieve info like this in laravel 6 or 7

User > hasMany  > Recipes
Recipe > belongsTo > User

I want to check if user id 2 present in users table then get only one post which id is 3

Comment: what you have tried and whats your problem please share

Comment: You have defined only user and recipes relation here. what about the post? share your DB schema or a model relationship so others can help you in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

[Query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#introduction) is for explicitly building SQL queries, and does not return instances of your models. [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) query builder, is similar but the result will contain the model(s) loaded with all their attributes, and has some handy functions for querying the relations you define in your models.

Given the limited information in your post, I am assuming when you say a post, you mean a recipe:

Query Builder:

```
DB::table('users')
  ->join('recipes', 'recipes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->select(['users.some_col', ... 'recipes.some_col'])
  ->where('users.id', 2)
  ->get();
```

If you have your models setup with the relations. You can use Eloquent like so:

```
User::where('id', 2)->with('recipes')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it would be like this:

```php
User::whereId($userId) //asuming it is 2
    ->with(['recipes' => function($q) use($recipeId) {
        $q->where('id', $recipeId); //assuming it is 3
    }])->first();
```

Comment: hello sir thanks for your help can I ask one more thing what is difference between 1>    User::whereId($userId) //asuming it is 2
    ->with(['recipes' => function($q) use($recipeId) {
        $q->where('id', $recipeId); //assuming it is 3
    }])->first();      and      2>       User::findOrFail(1)->recipes()->where('id','=','2')->get()
except first one will give both user and recipe data and other only recipe data, is there any difference between query which create behind the seens?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if i understand correctly:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(2); //auto 404 if user not found
$recipe = $user->Recipes()->where('id',3)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional eager loading for better performance.

```
$userId = 2;
$receiptId = 3;
$user = User::with(['receipts'=> function ($query) use($receiptId){
       $query->where('id', $receiptId);
 }
])->find($userId)
```